# Speech Recognition Python Having Strange Request Error

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech, google-speech-to-text-api

Speech Recognition with the following code just not working at all

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:
# read the audio data from the default microphone
audio = r.record(source, duration=4)
print("Recognizing...")
# convert speech to text
# recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
try:
    # for testing purposes, we're just using the default API key
    # to use another API key, use `r.recognize_google(audio, key="GOOGLE_SPEECH_RECOGNITION_API_KEY")`
    # instead of `r.recognize_google(audio)`
    print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said in English: -  " + r.recognize_google(audio, language = "en-US"))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

Here is the full error, it seems like the request is just failing, however this same code seems to work fine if I upload an audio file as the source. I have already checked by sr.Microphone and the default option is also linked correctly to my actual microphone...

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in recognize_google(self, audio_data, key, language, show_all)
    839         try:
--> 840             response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
    841         except HTTPError as e:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 

HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

RequestError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-50b94b08a896> in <module>
      3     audio = r.record(source, duration=4)
      4     print("Recognizing...")
----> 5     r.recognize_google(audio, language = "en-US")

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py in recognize_google(self, audio_data, key, language, show_all)
    840             response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
    841         except HTTPError as e:
--> 842             raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
    843         except URLError as e:
    844             raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {}".format(e.reason))

RequestError: recognition request failed: Bad Request
```

[image]

Comment: Add a new error exception: `except HTTPError as e`. Somehow the server is not accepting your request. May be `audio` has some wrong data format.

Answer (score 8):

This may not be the solution for the code you've written. But will help many others trying to use Google `SpeechRecognition` and getting the same vague error message.

I resolved the same issue by cutting short my audio input file to `less than 10 MB`.
Currently, the quota for synchronous requests is ~1 minute(10 MB).

Quoting [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas):

> There is a limit of 10 MB on all single requests sent to the API
> using local files. In the case of the *Recognize* and
> *LongRunningRecognize* methods, this limit applies to the size of the
> request sent. In the case of the StreamingRecognize method, the **10 MB** limit applies to both the initial *StreamingRecognize* request and the size of each individual message in the stream. Exceeding this limit will throw an error.

Comment: I wonder if you also had to deal with not getting the final SR result for `streamingRecognize`, [which appears to be a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64565542/1768303).

Comment: Luckily, I didn't

Answer (score 0):

As @YetAnotherBot mentioned, the likely problem was that the size was too big. At least that was happening for me. I solved this by dividing audio in chunks

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

def chunk_audio_and_save(audio_path, chunk_length=60000):  # chunk_length in milliseconds
    audio = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_path)
    length_audio = len(audio)
    chunk_paths = []
    for i, chunk in enumerate(range(0, length_audio, chunk_length)):
        chunk_audio = audio[chunk:chunk + chunk_length]
        chunk_path = f"temp_chunk_{i}.wav"
        chunk_audio.export(chunk_path, format="wav")
        chunk_paths.append(chunk_path)
    return chunk_paths
```

And then doing the transcribing:

```
for i, file_path in enumerate(chunk_file_paths):
    print(f"Transcribing chunk {i+1}/{len(chunk_file_paths)}...")
    transcript = transcribe_audio(file_path)
    full_transcript.append(transcript)
    os.remove(file_path)  # Clean up chunk file
```